# include .html in a .html

Tags: javascript, html, lamp, wamp, server-side-includes

I used the script

```
 <!--#include virtual="dontate.html" -->
```

to include a .html file into another .html file, but for some reason does not show up.

Any reason as to why?

I will be using WAMP and LAMP.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Do they have to be html files? Can you change PHP files?

Comment: they have to be .html files, if it was php, it was quick and easy

Answer (score 6):

This is using [server-side includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes).  You need to set it up on your server.  Despite the misleading "comment" syntax, it really has nothing to do with HTML.

Comment: give me an option without server setup

Comment: @Jean: copy & paste doesn't require a server.

Comment: Jean, you *could* read the comment nodes from the HTML DOM, then issue AJAX requests to load the content.  But that way madness lies.

Answer (score 3):

if there's php on the server you can just include the html file like so

```
<?php include "donate.html"; ?>
```

A lamp stack has php so you should be set.

However, the server may not be set up to run the file through php's interpreter. You can either set it to parse whatever the extension of the file is (being the file that is doing the including) or change it to something that is already set to be parsed (home.html -> home.php)

Comment: Well then you need to set up apache to interpret html files through php or copy and paste.

Another strategy could be to keep .php files on the server, but use .html links and use mod_rewrite to rewrite *.html to *.php seamlessly and on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

As your using wamp/lamp I found something that will work:

creating a .htaccess file and put the following in it

```
Options FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

Then change your html file extensions to .shtml (including the file that is to include a file)

So

```
<!--#include virtual="dontate.html" -->
```

Would become

```
<!--#include virtual="dontate.shtml" -->
```

This should work

**NOTE**:

The file is in the same directory as the file that is including it use:

```
<!--#include file="dontate.shtml" -->
```

If it is in a different directory use:

```
<!--#include virtual="folder/to/file/dontate.shtml" -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is the use of `virtual`

> The `file` parameter defines the included file as relative to the document path; the `virtual` parameter defines the included file as relative to the document root.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes

Comment: @Jean: what do you see when you view the source code from your browser? If you see `<!--#include... -->` then your server hasn't been set up to run the SSIs.

Comment: I want to include this .html file from one domain to other, turning on ssi is something I dont want.

I tried a document.write from a .js does not work though

Comment: @Jean Use php: `<?php echo file_get_contents('http://example.com/somefile.html'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<object data="file.html" width=400 height=200"></object>
```

If memory serves... I recall some border issues in IE but that should be sufficient for a primitive integration.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML spec, the **only** way to do this without server side scripting or server side includes is via iframes.

* note the bolded 'only'.

Answer (score -3):

**Guys..here is the answer**

*// jsfile.js*

```
var variable=""+
"";

document.write(variable);
```

****include .js file in html****

**thats it**

Comment: Um, no. That does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Probably because what you said isn't including a html file within another html file. Which in your question you asked for.